# php, realpath versus realpath + file_exists usage

Tags: php, performance

by performance reasons we should use only [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) instead of [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) + [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) when checking existence of a file or directory ??

CASE A ::

```
if(realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php")===false)
```

CASE B ::

```
if(file_exists(realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php"))===false)
```

i think `CASE A` do the job, and `CASE B` do the job two times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only is case B redundant (as realpath returns false if the path cannot be resolved or the file does not exist as per the [docs](https://www.php.net/realpath)), if the file does not exist, that is a bit silly.

Since this statement will return `FALSE`:

```php
realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php");
```

This:

```php
file_exists(realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php"));
```

Is really this:

```php
file_exists(FALSE); //!
```

---

As a side note: `realpath` will never return a "FALSY" value. By this I mean that it will never return something which `== FALSE` but does not `=== FALSE` (eg. `NULL`, `''`, 0, array()). Why? Well, the real path will always include a reference to the root — `/` in *nix systems (Mac, Unix, Linux) and `C:\` in Windows, and those two strings will evaluate to true when used as a boolean (say in an if, while, or for loop). This means you can just do:

```
if(!realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php")) // do something
```

Or, if you need to actually *have* the realpath, you can:

```
if(!($path = realpath(__DIR__."/../file.php")))
   // file does not exist
else
   // $path is now the full path to the file
```

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.  realpath() will return false if the file does not exist.  Case B is redundant.

https://www.php.net/realpath#refsect1-function.realpath-returnvalues

Answer (score 1):

They are nearly the same, but not exactly!

Case A will check if the path exists, `realpath` will return non-false values if the path after expanding it will point to a file **or folder**. Also if you pass `realpath` a `null`-value or an empty string it will return the current folder.

Case B can also check if the returned path is a regular file (as opposed to a directory!). If realpath resolves the path to an folder, an `is_file` call will return `false` and you can handle it from there.

So `realpath` will check if there is a file or folder (or symlink link thereto) at the given path and will expand empty values to the current directory. The extra `is_file` check can ensure you're working with a file not a folder.

Use case B (with `is_file` instead of `file_exists`) if you want to be sure you're working with a file, use case A if folders are also okay. :)

`file_exists` (in contrast with `is_file`) returns `true` for directories as well.

Comment: nice additional info, I did not know realpath behaviour when a null value or emptry string is used, thanks!!